# SignalR Groups.Add times out and fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm trying to add a member to a Group using SignalR 2.2. Every single time, I hit a 30 second timeout and get a "System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled." error.

From a GroupSubscriptionController that I've written, I'm calling:

```
 var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProjectHub>();
 await hubContext.Groups.Add(connectionId, groupName);
```

I've found this [issue](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3387) where people are periodically encountering this, but it happens to me every single time. I'm running the backend (ASP.NET 4.5) on one VS2015 launched localhost port, and the frontend (AngularJS SPA) on another VS 2015 launched localhost port.

I had gotten SignalR working to the point where messages were being broadcast to every connected client. It seemed so easy. Now, adding in the Groups part (so that people only get select messages from the server) has me  pulling my hair out...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That task cancellation error could be being thrown because the connectionId can't be found in the SignalR registry of connected clients.

How are you getting this connectionId? You have multiple servers/ports going - is it possible that you're getting your wires crossed?

Comment: That was it! Damn what a stupid mistake! I wasted hours on this! I had been periodically switching back and forth between testing on my localhost server and testing on a remote production server. The browser was negotiating with signalR on the production server, and then I was trying to give that connectionId to the local server (which obviously had no knowledge of that connectionId)

Answer (score 5):

I know there is an accepted answer to this, but I came across this once for a different reason.

First off, do you know what Groups.Add does?

I had expected `Groups.Add`'s task to complete almost immediately every time, but not so. `Groups.Add` returns a task that only completes, when the client (i.e. Javascript) acknowledges that it has been added to a group - this is useful for reconnecting so it can resubscribe to all its old groups. Note this acknowledgement is not visible to the developer code and nicely covered up for you.

The problem is that the **client may not respond** because they have disconnected (i.e. they've navigated to another page). This will mean that the `await` call will have to wait until the connection has disconnected (default timeout 30 seconds) before giving up by throwing a `TaskCanceledException`.

See http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups for more detail on groups

Comment: So is it normal to avoid this exception?

Comment: My conclusion was that you should generally not await Groups.Add - basically you should just assume it will work. If you really need to know when it works, then you will need to accept that you might be waiting for up to 30 seconds, and ignore the TaskCanceledException

Comment: Can you change the timeout value?

Comment: @Andy, yes but it has other side effects. The timeout is the amount of time that you don't hear from a client before you know they're gone. It's 30 seconds for a reason - to allow for an easy reconnection if the user has a blip in their network. I wouldn't recommend changing it - just don't await adding users to a group: it will either work or they've disconnected, so doesn't matter

Comment: @thab -- got it -- thanks a lot. I am going to assume that if I *don't* await, and send a message immediately to that group, that if they do eventually get added to that group within the 30 seconds, they will get that message?

Comment: @Andy yes that sounds right. Test it though (as ever)