# Task cancelled issue on await Groups.Add(groupId, Context.ConnectionId);

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

Task cancelled issue on await Groups.Add(groupId, Context.ConnectionId); still exists with WebSockets on Win8.
How can i increase signalr time out if this request is taking over 30 seconds.

A task was canceled.mscorlibStackTrace: ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

Please help me out.

Comment: You would not increase this timeout. I would search the reason why you have this timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you should not increase timeout. Please look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779343/signalr-groups-add-times-out-and-fails) as it explains the behavior you can observe. Appropriate action would be to check mentioned issue on client side and handle it accordingly, not increasing timeout time.

But as you asked it, here is how you can do it. Add this in Startup class.

```
// Make long polling connections wait a maximum of 110 seconds for a
// response. When that time expires, trigger a timeout command and
// make the client reconnect.
GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(110);

// Wait a maximum of 30 seconds after a transport connection is lost
// before raising the Disconnected event to terminate the SignalR connection.
GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

// For transports other than long polling, send a keepalive packet every
// 10 seconds.
// This value must be no more than 1/3 of the DisconnectTimeout value.
GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
```

You need to increase `DisconnectTimeout`. And there is small thing to keep in mind: order of setting `KeepAlive` and `DisconnectTimeout`  is important. If you will set `DisconnectTimeout` after you set `KeepAlive`, it will override `KeepAlive` value.

Comment: In my case i have only one hub where i did handshake and make group call.

Is there any way where SR provides us list of connected clients on server side where i can track status of client.
As i found after R&D we have to make custom list which repeatedly update on connected and disconnected events of SR.

Still have same issue how do get rid of this.please help me out.

Comment: No, there is no way to get list of connected users — it is true. You have to override OnConnected and OnDisconnected methods of a hub and build your list of connected users by yourself.